# "Ressource cannot be found" error when trying to filter items on webpage, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to filter products on my site. but when i click on my filter-button i get the error message that the ressource cannot be found.

*Description: HTTP 404. The resource or any of its dependencies may have been removed, renamed, or temporarily unavailable. Check the URL below and make sure it's spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /Views/Product/Index.cshtml*

here's my filter (simplified):

```
<form action="~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml" method="get">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <select class="event-type-select" name="category">
        <optgroup label="optgroup1"> 
          <option> option1</option>
          <option> option2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="optgroup2"> 
          <option> option3</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-default">filter!!!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

i didn't add any code to my controller. i dont know if that is the problem, but i also dont know what i would have to add in the controller then.

hope anyone can help me to solve this.

total beginner.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the server could not find what was requested.

You need to add this to the controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You need to add the Index.cshtml to the product folder under the folder Views [image]

If you are going to pass parameters to the page in order to apply a filter:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
    // Populate products or from a database
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    Product prod = new Product();
    prod.Name = "My Product";
    products.Add(prod);
    return View(products);
  }
}
```

The model would look like this under the folder Models:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Index.cshtml would have a model like so:

```
   @model List<Product>
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
<p> @product.Name </p>
}
```

For example purposes only this is a form that you would want to create if you only wanted to show selected Products from a dropdown:

```
        @model List<Product>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("FilterProduct", "Product", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <select id="filter" name="filter" multiple>
            <option value="">Products</option>
            @foreach (var product in Model)
            {
                <option value="@product.Name">@product.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
      <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-default">filter!!! 
</button>

    }
```

So now your controller would look like this:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
            // Populate products or from a database
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.Name = "My Product";
            products.Add(prod);
            return View(products);
      }

      public ActionResult FilterProduct(string[] filter)
      {
          // Filter your list of products based on the parameter
          return View("Index", products);
      }
}
```

Comment: but why do I need the code-part with "List<...> products = new..." in my controller? I create the list in my model already

Comment: @usernumber: That appears to have been a guess/assumption on this answer's part.  We don't know what your controller or model look like.  This answer goes into significant explanation and examples of MVC, but none of it is really relevant to the question being asked and *might* not be applicable to your code.  Your original question is simply about a 404 error, which is caused simply by the incorrect URL in your `<form>`.

Comment: @David My answer notes the 404 error and how one could solve it. It also has comments throughout the code and noted for example purposes. I tried judging on his initial question and code. All well.

Answer (score -1):

This is linking to a *view*:

```
"~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml"
```

You don't want to link to a page, you want to link to an *action* on the *controller*.  For example, if you have a controller action such as:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        // code to create a "product"
    }
}
```

Then, at least using default routing conventions (unless you modify them), the URL would be something like:

```
"/Products/Create"
```

(Note: In the above code I'm using "Products" instead of "Product".  It may be a slight nitpick, but semantically it usually works better to pluralize collections.  And the RESTful URLs for these actions are on what is semantically a collection.)

In MVC you're not creating "pages" that interact with each other.  You're creating "controllers" which get invoked by a request, perform logic using "models", and direct control to a "view" to render the result back to the user.

The ASP.NET MVC Framework has a variety of tooling available to help simplify much of this as well, such as providing "HTML Helpers" which will determine the URL for you based on the routing rules and the controller/action specified.  You'd definitely do well to walk through some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and continue to get more of a feel for how to use the framework.

Comment: But can I use my index-controller? ive tried this but still get the same error: public ActionResult Index(int? category)
        {
            return View(category);
        } and changed in my form "action="~/Views/Product/Index" also tried "action="~/Controllers/ProduktController/Index""

Comment: @usernumber: What's an "index-controller"?  Isn't your controller in this case called `ProductController`?  (Based on the `"Product"` folder your view is in.)  And where did `action="~/Controllers/ProduktController/Index"` come from?  That will of course give you the same error, and for the same reason, and is answered again by this same answer.  You can't just make up your own URLs and expect the system to figure out what you mean.  Please start with some introductory tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and learn how to use this framework.